# Getting count over() value after distinct executed

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query such as

```
select
distinct
t.*,
t.name + ' ' + t.lastname as customername
count(t.id) over() as count
from 
table t
inner join othertable o
on t.id = o.tableid
where t.blah = 'aaa'
```

The problem is that the `count over()` calculates the results before the `distinct` is executed and therefore returns an incorrect value.

I could remove the `distinct` and use `group by` but this will give the `count` for each group and I want the sum of those values.

I could do a subquery but the problem is this query is getting built up inside an application so I'd have to do some string manipulation to add the where clause to the subquery and main sql body.

Is there a way to get the `count` show the results after the distinct is executed?

Thanks

Comment: You could subselect with distinct the table t first then join

Comment: @JorgeCampos not sure i understand your comment

Comment: `select count(*) from (select distinct yadda yadaa.`

Comment: `from (select distinct t.*, t.name + ' ' + t.lastname as customername from table t) inner join .... `

Comment: `othertable o on t.id = o.tableid where t.blah = 'aaa'`

Comment: now people don't upvote the comments in the wrong order :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should solve the problem

```
select count(v.col_a) over() as count,
       v.*
from (select distinct t.col_a, t.col_b, ... --all columns you need
             t.name + ' ' + t.lastname as customername
      from table t
           inner join othertable o on t.id = o.tableid
      where t.blah = 'aaa') v
```

Comment: Of course you can replace `t.col_a, t.col_b, ...` with `t.*` in the subquery :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by`, but use the correct expression:

```
select t.*,
       t.name + ' ' + t.lastname as customername
       sum(count(t.id)) over() as total_count
from table t inner join
     othertable o
     on t.id = o.tableid
where t.blah = 'aaa'
group by . . .
```

Comment: That returns the same result :(

Comment: @Jon . . . Your question is quite unclear.  If this returns the same results as your query, then each group has only one element, and I can't figure out what results you really want.